# AS3.0 if/else if evaluation behaviour for velocity control

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement, conditional-statements, velocity

Sorry if this is obvious to others, but I can't get my head around something in ActionScript 3.0 (huge n00b btw)

I have this code for controlling velocity:

```
public function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
        {
            vx = -5;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
        {
            vx = 5;
        }

        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            vy = -5 
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
        {
            vy = 5;
        }
    }
```

When run, if I hold both LEFT and UP the Sprite moves Diagonally, but the fact that the two last conditionals (Keyboard.UP & Keyboard.DOWN) are elseifs should prevent them from being evaluated at all shouldnt it?

Is anyone able to shed some light on the behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press both buttons flash fires two independent events for each button. If you want to skip this case, you can make state flags (leftPressed, rightPressed, etc) for each button, change state in key handler and call the check motion method according to current states of each button.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want diagonal movement, set the velocity components to zero first like this:

```
public function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    vx = vy = 0; ////

    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        vx = -5;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        vx = 5;
    }

    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        vy = -5 
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        vy = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. good tip.
Just to clarify, I DO want diagonal but I wanted to understand WHY it was happening.